# How to add tabs to SlidingTabLayout at runtime

Tags: android, dynamic, tabs, android-viewpager, runtime

I've been trying for a while to add tabs to SlidingTabLayout at runtime in vain.
I get the name of the tab to add from a dialog. I'm trying to update the ViewPager of the mainActivity from the dialogFragment by getting a reference to the activity's ViewPager with this:

```
     ViewPager MyPager= (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
      MyPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

A failure.

A also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439621/how-to-add-a-tab-to-slidingtablayout) but i could not get it to work

```
      mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
      mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

      //But here is the problem, I can't find a way to refer to the 
      //Activity's SlidingTabLayout from the DialogFragment.

      tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
```

I Hope you can help me, Thanks.

Comment: There is one way you can use tabs in your fragment you can make the variable public static and in your fragment put : MainActivity.tabs  to use it; however it's bad practice ;

Comment: That's exactly why i'm stuck. I wondered if there was another way to do it (Abstract classes ,etc).